# How to match city code in telephone number with Informix SQL?

Tags: sql, informix

I have a couple of tables.  One contains dialed in phone numbers:

```
  num
  84951234567
  74957654321
  4951357246
  83855112345
  73855154321
  3855113524
```

Another has city codes:

```
  city_code      city_name
  495            Moscow
  38551          Kalmanka
```

I need to get the following:

```
  num             call_from
  84951234567     Moscow
  74957654321     Moscow
  4951357246      Moscow
  83855112345     Kalmanka
  73855154321     Kalmanka
  3855113524      Kalmanka
```

Phone number with city code always have 10 digits; it can be preceded with 7 or 8 or nothing. City code can have from 3 to 5 digits. Num is stored as VARCHAR.
Is this possible to solve this with SQL?

Comment: `JOIN ON city_code = LEFT(num, LEN(city_code))`

Comment: this matches only when NUM is without prefix, e.g. **495**1357246 - match, 7**495**7654321 - no match for **495** Moscow

Comment: This improvement gives much better result:
JOIN ON city_code = LEFT(RIGNT(num,10), LEN(city_code))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in another answer, is complicated to make this query efficient.
With this query you obtain what you want:

```
SELECT p.num, c.city_name
  FROM phones p, cities c
 WHERE LEFT(p.num, LENGTH(c.city_code)+1) MATCHES "*" || c.city_code || "*"
```

Because can be a prefix before the city_code in the phone number I take a substring of length(city_code) + 1

*** Edit ***

I make the join with `outer` to select phones without city_code, and because the phone with city code is always 10 digits, first I substring the last 10 digits of phone (as shown in another answer)

```
SELECT p.num, c.city_name
  FROM phones p, OUTER cities c
 WHERE c.city_code = LEFT(RIGHT(p.num, 10), LENGTH(c.city_code))
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! From practical test of this code:
        - numbers with codes that are not listed in city_codes table are missed from the output;
        - numbers without prefix are not listed, too;
        - some numbers are incorrectly matched, e.g. 3812217715 was detected as St.Petersburg (812), while this is number without prefix from Omsk (3812), which was not in a list of city_codes.

Comment: You are right, I made this query according to the data post in your question and I did not take into account what you say. Now I edit the answer with another one that I think will work

Comment: Using the Informix-style OUTER join is a bad idea in general terms — you should be using the JOIN notation from standard SQL.  It isn't even clear to me that you need to use an OUTER join.  You'll only select rows where the outer join produces a value rather than null for the `c` alias, so you may as well use a regular inner join anyway.

Comment: Using `SELECT p.num, c.city_name
  FROM phones p, cities c
 WHERE c.city_code = LEFT(RIGHT(p.num, 10), LENGTH(c.city_code))` (no OUTER) produces the same result; using `SELECT p.num, c.city_name
  FROM phones p JOIN cities c
 ON c.city_code = LEFT(RIGHT(p.num, 10), LENGTH(c.city_code))` does too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, the outer join is a habit for more than 30 years of Informix use that I have, why is a bad idea? I have never considered... The outer is necessary because Vodnik say that the numbers without city_code have to be in the output

Comment: The info requiring an outer join isn’t in the question as I read it, but it isn’t a major problem.  The Informix-style outer joins have, shall we say, curious semantics.  They’d not be an issue in the query shown, but if you filter the results on columns from the outer-joined tables, you can end up with rows you don’t expect in the output — rows that are correct according to the Informix algorithm but that would not be produced by the Standard SQL algorithm (and therefore not produced by Informix when you use the explicit LEFT JOIN (or RIGHT JOIN, or FULL JOIN) notations).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain to do efficiently.  Assuming that the city codes do not have prefixes of each other (like "123" and "1234"), you can try:

```
select d.*, c.city_name
from dialedin d join
     cities c
     on c.citycode = left(d.num, length(citycode))
```

This might not optimize well, because the `left()` has columns from both tables, and that generally precludes the use of an index.  An alternative is multiple joins:

```
select d.*, coalesce(c3.city_name, c4.city_name, c5.city_name)
from dialedin d left join
     cities c3
     on c3.citycode = left(d.num, 3) left join
     cities c4
     on c4.citycode = left(d.num, 4) left join
     cities c5
     on c5.citycode = left(d.num, 5)
```

Another advantage to the multiple `join` approach is that you can take the longest prefix that matches:

```
select d.*, coalesce(c3.city_name, c4.city_name, c5.city_name)
from dialedin d left join
     cities c5
     on c3.citycode = left(d.num, 5) left join
     cities c4
     on c4.citycode = left(d.num, 4) and c5.citycode is null left join
     cities c3
     on c5.citycode = left(d.num, 3) and c4.citycode is null
```

Comment: This code works fine when left(d.num, N) is replaced by left(right(d.num,10), N). I tested on a small DB (~7000 recors), so can't say for performance yet

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using an Informix 14.10 server and not an earlier version such as 12.10 or 11.70 (or anything older, which is out of support), then you could consider:

```
WITH mapped_cities(city_code, city_name) AS
     (SELECT        city_code, city_name FROM city_codes
      UNION
      SELECT '7' || city_code, city_name FROM city_codes
      UNION
      SELECT '8' || city_code, city_name FROM city_codes
     )
SELECT d.num, m.city_name AS call_from
  FROM dialled_phone_numbers AS d
  JOIN mapped_cities AS m
    ON m.city_code = LEFT(d.num, LENGTH(m.city_code))
```

With sample tables and data set up using the following (some data from the question, some data from the comments):

```
CREATE TABLE dialled_phone_numbers(num VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE city_codes(city_code VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, city_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO city_codes VALUES('812', 'St.Petersburg');
INSERT INTO city_codes VALUES('3812', 'Omsk');
INSERT INTO city_codes VALUES('495', 'Moscow');
INSERT INTO city_codes VALUES('38551', 'Kalmanka');

INSERT INTO dialled_phone_numbers VALUES('3812217715');
INSERT INTO dialled_phone_numbers VALUES('3855113524');
INSERT INTO dialled_phone_numbers VALUES('4951357246');
INSERT INTO dialled_phone_numbers VALUES('73855154321');
INSERT INTO dialled_phone_numbers VALUES('74957654321');
INSERT INTO dialled_phone_numbers VALUES('84951234567');
```

the query shown produces the output:

```
num          call_from
VARCHAR(11)  VARCHAR(25)
3812217715   Omsk
3855113524   Kalmanka
4951357246   Moscow
73855154321  Kalmanka
74957654321  Moscow
84951234567  Moscow
```

Clearly, an ORDER BY clause could be used to sequence things better.

The WITH clause generates a list of prefixes with 'nothing', or 7 or 8 as the prefix.  This is then used to join with the start of the numbers in the `dialled_phone_numbers` table, using the join condition from the first code segment in [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60078753/15168).

If you have an older version of Informix without the WITH clause (common table expression, or CTE), then you could use a temporary table to hold the results of the UNION sub-query used in the WITH clause and join with that instead.

Comment: Thank you for ideas, @Jonathan! I'm using Informix V12.10 as part of another product.

Comment: Then the `WITH` clause solution won't work directly, but: `SELECT        city_code, city_name FROM city_codes
      UNION
      SELECT '7' || city_code, city_name FROM city_codes
      UNION
      SELECT '8' || city_code, city_name FROM city_codes INTO TEMP mapped_cities` and then using the body of the query will work.  You can also use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mapped_cities` to ensure that the temp table is created afresh each time (or use the value from last time if your `city_codes` table rarely changes).

Answer (score 0):

As solution mentioned by Paul in comments, you an also modify it as

```
        JOIN ON city_code = LEFT(num, 5) or city_code = LEFT(num, 3)
```

**EDIT**

Lets have a look at possible scenarios. If you have max 5 digit code and also prefixed by a number 7 or 8, then total of 6 digits would be there. Your generalized `join` clause will be

```
       JOIN ON LEFT(num, 6) LIKE '%'+city_code+'%'
```

Hope this might work.

Comment: This doesn't match prefixed NUM: **495**1357246 - match, 7**495**7654321 - no match for **495** Moscow

Comment: Have made some changes in solution, please have a look

Comment: Using `%` matches any number of characters; that is not safe — a city code can appear accidentally at the end of a number.

Answer (score 0):

You are interested in

- all 10-digit numbers
- all 11-digit numbers that start with 7
- all 11-digit numbers that start with 8

Select those and outer join the cities (or inner join them, if you only want to see matches or even see it guaranteed that you only get matches):

```
select
  p.phone_number,
  c.city
from phonecalls p
left join cities c on right(p.phone_number, 10) like c.city_code || '%'
where length(p.phone_number) = 10
or (length(p.phone_number) = 11 and p.phone_number like '7%')
or (length(p.phone_number) = 11 and p.phone_number like '8%')
order by c.city, right(p.phone_number, 10), p.phone_number;
```

(If this is too slow, you may want to consider writing a user defined function to get the 10-digit number from those 10/11-digit ones and create a function index on this. The query would then read something like `select ... join cities c on ten_digit_number(p.phone_number) like c.city_code || '%' ... where ten_digit_number(p.phone_number) is not null`.)